# Read image from datastore into the <img> tag

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, image-uploading, app-engine-ndb

Hi I am trying to upload an image for an entity and get it into another page into an image tag but cannot get it done.

Writing in whole blob content into response is working but it is not visible if am trying to get the  blob content into an  tag in a html page.

Following is the code. Please help

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import mimetypes
import logging


HTML_POST_PAGE = \
"""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
"""


OUTPUT_HTML_PAGE = """
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Serving image dynamically.</h1>
<img src='/dyimg_serve?img_id=%s'></img>
</body>
</html>
"""

#Hardcoded value for Key name
email_id = "ryan@gmail.com"

#Updated Image Upload
class MyUser(ndb.Model):
    file_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob = ndb.BlobProperty()


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(HTML_POST_PAGE)

#Handler for image upload
class FileUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
            #Creating entity with fixed id
            my_user = MyUser(id=email_id)

            #Below lines to be added in the main code to put image in datastore
            file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
            file_name = file_upload.filename
            my_user.file_name = file_name
            my_user.blob = file_upload.file.read()
            userKey = my_user.put()

            #Navigating to other page to read image
            self.response.out.write(OUTPUT_HTML_PAGE)


#Handler to read image into the <img> tag in the OUTPUT_HTML_PAGE 
class DynamicImageServe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        oldUser = MyUser.get_by_id(email_id)
        if oldUser != None and oldUser.blob != None:
##            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(oldUser.file_name)[0]
            self.response.write(oldUser.blob)
        else:
            self.response.write('Error while fetching image data')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage ),('/file_upload',FileUpload),('/dyimg_serve',DynamicImageServe),], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the src attribute of your img tag on your output page.

```
<img src="/dyimg_serve"></img>
```

Comment: The same code after fixing the img tag is working as expected on one my appengine instances.

http://imageserveapp.appspot.com/

Code: [link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ddd36c4fe703a5202d5

Comment: Thanks got it running too.